# How to sort the index of a xarray Dataset/DataArray?

Tags: python, pandas, python-xarray

I am creating a `DataArray` from multiple slices along the time dimension and stumbled across the `'index must be monotonic for resampling'` error when trying to resample which I guess says that my time index is not sorted. I did not pay attention to the order in when I `concat()`inated them.

`# TODO: sort instead of raising an error`

is to be found in the code where the error is raised.

My question: How would I sort the indices of my `DataArray`s within a `DataSet`? I could not find anything like `sort_index()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could reindex on the sorted index - `.reindex(time=sorted(dataset.time))`

Not as elegant as `sort_index()` but it should work

EDIT: @scottclowe points out that xarray since added `.sortby()`, so use that! http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.sortby.html

Comment: Thanks! I chose to load my pieces in the correct order in the first place to avoid that situation. Good to know still!

Answer (score 10):

There is now a [sortby()](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.sortby.html) method which can be used.

```
da = da.sortby('time')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add **.values** to get sorted to work correctly. Where my time.values is a datetime64[ns]. Xarray v0.10.0.

```
.reindex(time=sorted(dataset.time.values))
```